# SCSS mixin settings

Tags: css, scss-mixins

I am creating a mixin in scss, it is either supposed to set a `padding-left` or `padding-right`, the value of the padding is passed in the mixin params, the direction should be concluded depending on a root variable that I am setting in JavaScript according to a specific logic. If the `var(--dir)` is set to "left", the padding will be `padding-left` in the mixin, if it is set to "right", the padding will be `padding-right` in the mixin.

This is my mixin code, but it doesn't work, it's because scss doesn't treat the `var(--dir)` as variable that has a value, are there any other solutions that I can handle this? maybe somehow try to get the value of an attribute that is set on the html root?

```
@mixin custom-padding($value) {
  $dir: var(--dir);

  @if $dir == "right" {
    padding-left: $value;
  } @else {
    padding-right: $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code ... try: ``` CODE ``` please read: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: ``` @mixin custom-padding($value) {
  $dir: var(--dir);

  @if $dir == "right" {
    padding-left: $value;
  } @else {
    padding-right: $value;
  }
}```

Comment: sorry, updated now.

Comment: Welcome! The problem you're having is that SCSS is compiled, not dynamic. It's not that it doesn't treat `var(--dir)` as a variable, it's the mixin doesn't exist to assign the `var(--dir)` and compare. What is your use case for this? How are you using this mixin in your SCSS? What elements are you targeting? Update your question with use and use case.

Comment: okay so I'm trying to use this mixin in a next.js project, my problem is that i have 2 languages, english and arabic, upon language switch (which is a state in my app) I am was setting this var(--dir) to a specific values, and i was trying to leverage this value so i can avoid duplicating my files, but i am not sure if you have another workaround for this?